# I've installed java zulu-17, but my vscode is saying I'm using java se-16 at the bottom of my terminal

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I was wondering if this is normal: these are my Visual Studio Code settings for Java runtime config:
[image: this is the runtime config on vscode for java]

When I open my project this is what I see:
[image: here, it says I'm on java se-16]

This is my java version when I check in terminal:
[image]

Does this mean if I want to use JavaFX, I have to install the Java 16 version?

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I don't use Java from Visual Studio Code, but isn't it displaying JavaSE-16 related to the fact your project is marked as a Java 16 project?

Comment: Zip distributions do not register with the system java command.  Set your $PATH

Comment: [*OpenJFX*](https://openjfx.io/) (*JavaFX*) version 17 requires Java 11 or later. So no need to downgrade OpenJFX whether you are using Java 16 or Java 17. But you should move from Java 16 to 17 for other reasons: [Java 16 has reached end-of-life](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-se-support-roadmap.html), and Java 17 is a Long-Term Support (LTS) version.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen hi how would I do this, do I have to set a JAVA_HOME directory too?

Comment: I have misread the question.  A given Java release usually supports several earlier releases as well. Your Workspace is configured to Java 16 which the JDK you have installed can be used with.  You will need to configure the workspace to be Java 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Project JDKs**(`java.configuration.runtimes`) and **Java Tooling Runtime**(`java.home`) can be configured separately, which means you can specify different jdk for project and java extension.

But Java17 is not supported now, as you can see it's not accepted. You may try jdk16 as java extension recommends.

[image]